# Getting MismatchedInputException on consumer kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, json-deserialization

#### Getting MismatchedInputException on consumer kafka

I'm posting to a kafka queue by swagger and It is possible to see that the topic receives the message, this is checked with Kafka tools. I can download the message through Kafka tools (now offset explorer). The problem is that the message is not deserialized in the consumer.

3 different springboot projects are being used: one for the producer, another project for the consumer and a commons that is used as a dependency for the producer and the consumer. The commons has the entities, the data transfer objects and the mappers that in this case Mapstruct is being used. It is running kafka locally.

This error is received in consumer:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `com.doo.boo.foo.dto.ShippingCompanyDTO2` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{"companyName":"Some Something","cnpj":"58890252000113"}')
 at [Source: (String)""{\"companyName\":\"Some Something\",\"cnpj\":\"32635577000166\"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1495) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:197) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597) ~[jackson-databind-2.13.4.jar:2.13.4]
    at com.doo.boo.foo.stubs.utils.JsonConverter.toObject(JsonConverter.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

**Method of the controller Class in which data is sent to the producer using json format:**

```
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "200 OK. Return success.") })
    @ApiOperation(value = "Salva uma transportadora")
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO<ShippingCompanyDTO2>> saveShippinCompany(
            @RequestBody ShippingCompanyDTO2 shippingCompanyDTO2) {
        UUIDService.generate();
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseDTO<>(shippingCompanyService2.saveShippingCompany(shippingCompanyDTO2)));
    }
```

**json sent to topic via endpoint using swagger:**

{
"companyName": "Some Something",
"cnpj": "58890252000113"
}

**Message downloaded from kafka topic using kafka tools:**

"{\"companyName\":\"Some Something\",\"cnpj\":\"58890252000113\"}"

**CONSUMER:**

```
@Service
public class WacQueueConsumer2Impl implements WacQueueConsumer2 {

    private JsonConverter<ShippingCompanyDTO2> jsonConverter;

    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public WacQueueConsumer2Impl(ObjectMapper objectMapper, KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        this.jsonConverter = new JsonConverter<>(objectMapper, ShippingCompanyDTO2.class);
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    @KafkaListener(topics = WacProperties.TOPIC_WAC_IN, groupId = WacProperties.GROUP_ID)
    public void consumeWacQueue2(String shippingCompanyDTO2String) {
        UUIDService.generate();
        ShippingCompanyDTO2 shippingCompanyDTO2 = this.jsonConverter.toObject(shippingCompanyDTO2String); ** //  Exception Occurs here **
        LogService.information(shippingCompanyDTO2, "Objeto recuperado da fila");

    }
}
```

**Entity in the Commons project shared with the producer and consumer:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TTST_TSPA2")
public class ShippingCompany2 implements Serializable { // Testar depois com contructor com argumentos e sem argumentos

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4550596164870602490L;

    public ShippingCompany2(Long id, String companyName, String cnpj) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public ShippingCompany2() {
        super();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "STST_TSPA2")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "STST_TSPA2", sequenceName = "STST_TSPA2", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "CG_TSPA", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TE_NOME_TSPA", nullable = true)
    private String companyName;

    @Column(name = "TE_CNPJ", nullable = true)
    private String cnpj;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShippingCompany2 [id=" + id + ", companyName=" + companyName + ", cnpj=" + cnpj + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(cnpj, companyName, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ShippingCompany2 other = (ShippingCompany2) obj;
        return Objects.equals(cnpj, other.cnpj) && Objects.equals(companyName, other.companyName)
                && Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }
```

**Data transfer object of Entity also in Commons project:**

```
/*@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Data*/
public class ShippingCompanyDTO2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6928928565459734304L;

    public ShippingCompanyDTO2(Long id, @JsonProperty("companyName") String companyName,
            @JsonProperty("cnpj") String cnpj) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public ShippingCompanyDTO2() {
        super();
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    private Long id;

    private String companyName;

    private String cnpj;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ShippingCompanyDTO2 [id=" + id + ", companyName=" + companyName + ", cnpj=" + cnpj + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(cnpj, companyName, id);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        ShippingCompanyDTO2 other = (ShippingCompanyDTO2) obj;
        return Objects.equals(cnpj, other.cnpj) && Objects.equals(companyName, other.companyName)
                && Objects.equals(id, other.id);
    }

}
```

**`JsonConvert.class`**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import com.doo.boo.foo.stubs.handler.exception.ApiException;
import com.doo.boo.foo.stubs.handler.exception.ExceptionCodeEnum;


public class JsonConverter<T> {

    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Class<T> typeParameterClass;

    @Autowired
    public JsonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper, Class<T> typeParameterClass) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.typeParameterClass = typeParameterClass;
    }

    public String toJSON(Object value) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new ApiException(ExceptionCodeEnum.JSON_PROCESSING_EXCEPTION, e);
        }
    }

    public T toObject(String value) {

        try {
            return (T) objectMapper.readValue(value, this.typeParameterClass);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new ApiException(ExceptionCodeEnum.JSON_MAPPING_EXCEPTION, e);
        }
    }

}
```

**consumer project's application.properties**

kafka.bootstrap-servers=192.168.0.192:9092

kafka.topic.wac.send=tp-wac-send_local

kafka.groupId=wms-registry-shipping-company

logging.level.com.fasterxml.jackson=TRACE

**KafkaConsumerConfig**

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
    

    @Value("${kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServer;
    
    //@Value("wms-registry-shipping-company")
    @Value("${kafka.groupId}")
    private String groupId;
    
    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String,String> kafkaTemplate;

    
    public KafkaConsumerConfig() {
        super();
    }
    
    
    
    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer() {return new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfigs()); }
    
    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServer);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 80000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 20000);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
        
        return props;
        
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(String.class));
    }
    
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> KafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

**Commons project pom.xml**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaa-bbb-cadastro-fornecedor-commons</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <version-map-struct>1.3.0.Final</version-map-struct>
        <lombok-version>1.18.20</lombok-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${version-map-struct}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${version-map-struct}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

**pom.xml of the Consumer project**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>br.com.x</groupId>
    <artifactId>aaa-bbb-cadastro-fornecedor-consumer-ms</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>aaa-bbb-cadastro-fornecedor-consumer-ms</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>-->
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.20</lombok-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>br.com.x</groupId>
            <artifactId>aaa-bbb-cadastro-fornecedor-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\DEV\external_jars_to_add\aaa-bbb-cadastro-fornecedor-commons-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--        <dependency> -->
        <!--            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> -->
        <!--            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId> -->
        <!--        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--            <dependency>-->
        <!--            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>-->
        <!--            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>-->
        <!--            <version>12.2.0.1</version>-->
        <!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <!--            <version>12.2.0.1</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Hoxton.SR4</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In the error stack it shows that the problem would be that a valid constructor was not found, so I created constructor with argument and without argument in the entity and in the DTO and even so the problem continues. Using lombok getter, setters, constructors annotations the same problem occurs. The original object is much more complex, I left it with only 2 fields to try to make debugging the problem easier.

That part of the error, specifically ***Source: (String)""{*** maybe it could mean something else, but I don't understand. It seems to be a deserialization issue.
[Source: (String)""{"id":13,"companyName":"Pfizer Medicamentos e Participacoes LTDA","cnpj":"11.902.941/0001-37"}""; line: 1, column: 1]
Can anybody help me?

I already simplified the input object (input json), because it is more complex.
I already tried creating constructors with and without arguments explicitly and also using lombok.
I had seen in another question on stackoverflow that they suggested putting the @JsonProperty( annotation in all entity and dto fields, I did that but it didn't solve it.

What I expect is the consumer's consumeWacQueue2 method to execute the last line of the log indicating that the queue was successfully consumed:
LogService.information(shippingCompanyDTO2, "Objeto recuperado da fila");  // ---> getting here everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a wrong configuration of the Kafka consumer. There is a JSON deserializer configured. But you have implemented a custom deserialization class (JsonConverter). You should configure a simple string deserializer.

Change this:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
```

Like this:

```
props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
```

Comment: Yes, your suggestion solved the problem. It was a misconfiguration issue in Kafka consumer
Thank you very much